# Trying to create a dropdown using two columns' data

Tags: validation, google-sheets, dropdown

I have an inventory spreadsheet with the list of items on the "Inventory" tab in Google Sheets:

[image: Inventory list]

On the Calendar tab, I would like to select the brand (Inventory, column A) and the item (Inventory, column B). However, I would like the Calendar tab, column B to be "smart" enough to only show me items in the dropdown that are for the brand I selected in the Calendar tab, column A.

[image: Calendar tab]

For example, if I choose Melt Cosmetics from the dropdown in the Calendar tab, column A, the dropdown for column B in the Calendar tab should only have "Bad Side Zodiac - Fire" available. If I choose Menagerie for column A, Column B should have Killer Purr and Sugar High as the only options available to select. I am currently populating both columns A and B in the Calendar tab using data validation, but column B is displaying everything from the Inventory tab, column B. Column C on the Calendar tab is just a concatenation of values from Cols A and B.

Is there a straightforward way to configure the dropdown in column B so it populates as I've described above?

I have tried different data validation options, but cannot get it to do what I want. I'm wondering if there's a way to combine a VLOOKUP with data validation, but I can't quite conceptualize how to do that.

Comment: Use named ranges that are dynamic. It's a pain, but it works.